# Implementing a system call for CPU hotplug

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm, kernel, system-calls

My goal is to implement a system call in linux kernel that enables/disables a CPU core.

First, I implemented a system call that disbales CPU3 in a 4-core system.

The system call code is as follows:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/slab.h>
#include <asm/uaccess.h>
#include <asm/unistd.h>
#include <linux/cpumask.h>
#include <linux/smp.h>

asmlinkage long sys_new_syscall(void)
{
    unsigned int cpu3;

    set_cpu_online (cpu3, false) ;          /* clears the CPU in the cpumask */
    printk ("CPU%u is offline\n", cpu3);


    return 0;
}
```

The system call was registered correctly in the kernel and I enabled  'cpu hotplug' feature during kernel configuration. See picture

[image: Kernel configuratione]

However, the kernel failed to compile in the last stage and I got this error:

```
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
E: mkinitramfs failure cpio 141 gzip 1
update-initramfs: failed for /boot/initrd.img-4.6.7-rt13-v7+ with 1.
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools exited with return code 1
arch/arm/boot/Makefile:99: recipe for target 'install' failed
make[1]: *** [install] Error 1
arch/arm/Makefile:333: recipe for target 'install' failed
make: *** [install] Error 2
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 2):

```
gzip: stdout: No space left on device
```

This issue has nothing to do with your code. Your `/boot` filesystem is full.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I am compiling linux on raspberry pi3/ModelB. Any idea how can I fix this problem ?

Comment: You need more space. I think you should compile the kernel better on other hardware.